# Run program on tomcat server with Javascript, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, shell

so, here is the thing, I need to run .jar I've programmed myself on a server.

On the otherside, that server is also a webserver, so it displays webpages and so. Those webpages are written in simple HTML and JavaScript.

So, here is the thing:

is there a way to run my program when users perform click on links in the webpage?
I created a function in Javascript, but I cannot make it work, as long as I don't know how to run shell commands in Javascript.

The execution of the program is totally transparent to the user, and what it basically does is to search content in some documents in order to update the html that is shown to the user.

Any ideas? Hope I made myself clear.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is it written in JavaScript instead of Java?

Comment: I assume you didn't programmed the .jar but you programmed java and used a suitable webframework (java native stuff/Spring?). The compiler produced the .jar based on your java file. It would be helfull if we know the framework you used.

Comment: I programmed the .jar myself in Java language, but it has to be called from a webpage, so I though Javascript would do the call...

Comment: Well if you need to do things on the server, then something on the page needs to initiate an HTTP request to trigger activity on the server. Remember that your pages and JavaScript run on computers far, far away from where your .jar file and web application run. :-)

Comment: Yes, in the onclick method of the page, I would like to trigger the execution of my program in the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really can't run shell commands in JavaScript.

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking to do some sort of remote process execution.

Is your JAR file on the other server - is it running as part of a web server, I.E. as a servlet in an application container like Tomcat, such that your code can be executed by calling HTTP methods?  (If not, you may want to start out with doing this.)  If so, then you'll need to have your JavaScript make the HTTP call to the server to execute its code.  A common way of doing this today is through the use of AJAX - and you can use something like jQuery to help with this.  The response from this AJAX request (could be XML, JSON, or pre-formatted HTML) could contain the details to "update the HTML that is shown to the user".

Comment: Well, you *can* run shell commands at the instigation of JavaScript by going through the Java runtime, if the script is running in Rhino on the server. What's not clear is *why* one would do that, though personally I've been in the situation so it's not totally outlandish.

Comment: @Pointy - correct, but my answer is assuming this JavaScript is client-side JavaScript, given "Those webpages are written in simple HTML and JavaScript" in the OP.

Comment: The process is the following:

The user navigates through a website, and clicks on a link, that leads him to an information page, e.g. info.html.

When they click on it, I want my .jar program to run and update the info.html file with information from another document and then, display the page info.html, after the program has finished.

It's just a way to keep the information in the webpages always updated.

Comment: So, I assume it's impossible to do what I wanted to do in the very beginning, right?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is put the html, javascript, and a jsp page in the same war file, and then run it on tomcat. Not the best way, but definitely the quickest.

EDIT:

So to clarify, the JSP page will get invoked by the click (ajax call, use jquery), and renders some json/xml. The success handler for the ajax call takes the jsp response and updates your html page. So the jsp runs on the server, but the html/javascript runs in the browser.

If you want to make if fancier, you can use spring web-mvc and write a controller instead of a jsp page. It has the same overall effect either way.

Comment: This won't help create the desired interaction between the client-side code (JavaScript on web page) and the server-side code requested by the OP.

Comment: sure it will. Make the jsp page render xml or json, and make an ajax call from a different html page.